# Ansible - How to loop and get attributes of new EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm creating a set of new EC2 instances using this play

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Provision a set of instances
      ec2:
        assign_public_ip: yes
        aws_access_key: XXXXXXXXXX
        aws_secret_key: XXXXXXXXXX
        group_id: XXXXXXXXXX
        instance_type: t2.micro
        image: ami-32a85152
        vpc_subnet_id: XXXXXXXXXX
        region: XXXXXXXXXX
        user_data: "{{ lookup('file', '/SOME_PATH/cloud-config.yaml') }}"
        wait: true
        exact_count: 1
        count_tag:
          Name: Demo
        instance_tags:
          Name: Demo
      register: ec2
    - name: Add new CoreOS machines to coreos-launched group
      add_host: hostname="{{ item.public_ip }}" groups=coreos-launched
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      wait_for: host="{{ item.public_dns_name }}" port=22 delay=60 timeout=320
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

Now, I need to create an SSL/TLS certificate for every of those new machines. To do so, I require their private IP. Yet, I don't know how to access the "{{ ec2.instances }}" I registered in the previous play.

I tried something, in the same playbook, to do something like this

```
- hosts: coreos-launched
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Find the current machine IP addresse
      command: echo "{{ item.private_ip }}" > /tmp/private_ip
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
      sudo: yes
```

But without any success. Is there a way to use the "{{ ec2.instances }}" items inside a same playbook but in a different play?

-- EDIT --

Following Theo advices, I manage to get the instances attributes using

```
- name: Gather current facts
  action: ec2_facts
  register: ec2_facts
- name: Use the current facts
  command: echo "{{ ec2_facts.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_local_ipv4 }}"
  with_items: "{{ ec2_facts }}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to learn about a return structure (short of the documentation) is to wrap it in a debug task.

```
  - name: Debug ec2 variable
    debug: var=ec2.instances
```

From there, follow the structure to get the variable you seek.

Also (following the idempotence model), you can use the [ec2_remote_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_remote_facts_module.html) module to get the facts from the instances and call them in future plays/tasks as well.

See [Variables -- Ansible Documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables) for more info about calling registered variables.